# SVN: share common libraries / code across projects

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I'm in the process of re-structuring our existing code base. We are moving to SVN and expecting an increase in software activity and I need a scalable and robust structure.

I hope our requirements are not too dissimilar to those of other companies so I'll get some feedback from you guys.

**The problem**

I have a number of projects: libraries and applications. Applications depend on the libraries and also some of the libraries depend on each other.

We have a number of products. Each product is an MSI that contains some of the libraries and some of the apps.

The projects are C++ and the dependencies between them are the header files and import libraries / DLLs – we’re currently developing under Windows but will port to MACOS and Linux eventually.

Although each project is an independent entity for some of them we end-up updating several of them at the same time. For example, while working on app_0, we might change some code in lib_a (maybe bug fix, added feature, etc.).
But we don't want to force developers having to always checkout the sources for a project's dependencies.

**Potential solution**

Each project is in its own directory in SVN and has a 'dependencies.txt' file listing the headers, .libs and .dlls it requires and where these should be created on disk. Once a project is checked out, a script automatically parses this file to retrieve the dependencies. The header files are retrieved from SVN (partial checkout) while the binaries are taken from a server.

Projects follow the usual trunk / tags / branches structure.

On disk, each project lives in its own directory, in a flat structure. An output directory contains binaries, either generated by building a project or copied from a server as a result of processing the 'dependencies.txt' file.

- output

  - win32_debug

    - lib_a.lib
    - lib_a.dll
- lib_a

  - sources
  - public

    - lib_a.h
    - other.h
- project_1

  - dependencies.txt
  - build
  - sources

    - project_1.cpp

This structure means that we can work on project_1 without needing to checkout the sources for lib_a. But we can still checkout the library into './lib_a' and work with its sources without any modification to project_1 since the location of headers and import library remains the same.

An 'installer' project is used to release the software. This project will checkout all the projects required for the release and build them.

During a release a 'release' branch is created for all projects. All changes that should go into the release are committed to it. This way we just need to run an update on the checkout (tracking release branch) to get the latest changes.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Looking for advice on how to solve the stated problem and / or comments on the solution I came up with.

Comment: @JPh - What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways of handling dependency issues:

- Use a release repository and treat your *libraries* and *header files* as released software. You could use `wget` to pull out the correct version of your libraries and header files. The advantage is that you're not checking in big blocks of binary code into your Subversion repository. Subversion does handle binary files, but they take up a lot of room in your repository.
- You can use the `svn:externals` property. This allows you to automatically include another repository directory in another directory. However, be very, very careful with it!

Imagine you have the following:

```
trunk/project_A
trunk/project_B
trunk/subproject
```

You want to include `trunk/subproject` in `project_A`, and you set the following attribute on `project_A`:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals "/trunk/subproject subproject" .
```

When you branch project_A, your subproject will still be on trunk. Not what you want. If you tag `project_A`, that tag will not be a snapshot because `subproject` is still pointing to trunk. There are a few ways to handle this:

- Use relative directories. That is, `svn propset "svn:externals ../subproject" subproject .`. This will ensure when you branch `project_A`, it will look at your subproject's branch and not trunk. When you tag `project_A`. the tag will be pointing to subproject's same tag. The problem is that you have to branch and tag your subproject with project_A.
- Use a specific version. You can use the `-r` parameter to fix a particular version of subproject to project_A, or you can simply use a tag. Either way, you've frozen subproject in time. Word o' warning: If someone checks out project_A, they can modify subproject even if it's on a tag directory. You will need some sort of pre-commit hook that will prevent someone from changing a tag.

Comment: Apologies for messing with the comments - didn't realised pressing <enter> posted them! (1) Release repo sounds good. (2) Relative URLs for externals sound interesting, will look into it. Not sure how to deal with multiple projects referencing the same lib as the lib would get checked out multiple times...

Comment: Take a look at the chapter in the on-line Subversion manual on [External Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)